# Angular - Parent component is in stuck when child component is still loading

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and a child component ( basically a context menu ).
When I right-click on the parent's table row, the child component shows as a context menu.
When I click link on context menu , it open the link in new tab.
It's so far ok, but the problem is, I cannot click or make any interaction on parent page before the new page finished loading.  How can I prevent for that ?

This is code for parent component's table row

```
 <tr (contextmenu)="onrightClick($event,rowData['id'])">


 onrightClick(event, data) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.contextmenuX = event.clientX;
        this.contextmenuY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        this.contextMenuRouterLink = 'myLink/' + data;
        this.contextmenu = true;
    }
    //disables the menu
    disableContextMenu() {
        this.contextmenu = false;
    }
```

This is how I add child component(context menu) in parent page

```
<div *ngIf="contextmenu">
    <app-context-menu-open-in-new-tab [x]="contextmenuX" [y]="contextmenuY" [routerLink]="contextMenuRouterLink" (disableContextMenu)="disableContextMenu()"></app-context-menu-open-in-new-tab>
</div>
```

This is code for child component
**Note:** I use eventEmitter to close the context menu on parent page .

```
<div class="contextmenu" [ngStyle]="{'left.px': x, 'top.px': y}">
    <a (click)="onLinkClick($event);" href="{{routerLink}}" target="_blank">Open your data in new tab</a>
</div>

 onLinkClick(event) {
       this.disableContextMenu.emit(null);
       event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add

```
rel="noopener" to you link
```

That prevents that the source page keeps waiting for the new page to finish loading/executing.